# Does Intel HD Graphics 3000 support hardware acceleration for Flash?

Tags: flash, intel-core-i5, integrated-graphics, hardware-acceleration

If I were to skip a discrete video card and just get an Intel Core i5 2500k CPU, would the integrated GPU support hardware acceleration for Flash? If so, is that just on Windows? What about Mac? Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows, yes, for mac, maybe, for linux, there's no mention of it.

[source](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/systemreqs/)
On windows

> Video hardware acceleration support
>
> Flash Player 10.3 supports
>   hardware-accelerated decoding of H.264
>   video on Windows and Mac computers
>   with supported hardware and drivers,
>   providing enhanced video performance.
>   For the latest information on
>   supported hardware and drivers, visit
>   the following vendor sites:
>
> Intel hardware decoding of H.264 video
>   in Flash Player 10.3 is supported on
>   the Intel 4 Series chipset family and
>   the 2010 Intel Core processor family
>   with Intel HD Graphics, starting with
>   graphics driver version 15.16.5.2021
>   (8.15.10.2021) for 32/64-bit Windows
>   Vista and Windows 7.
>
> For the Atom/GMA 500 chipset, hardware
>   decoding is supported starting with
>   graphics driver version 5.2.1.2020
>   (8.14.10.2020) for 32-bit Windows 7.
>   Systems using GMA 500 video decoding
>   should use a Windows Aero theme for
>   optimal full-screen playback
>   performance.

on OS X

> Mac OS X hardware decoding support
>
> On Mac computers, hardware decoding of
>   H.264 video in Adobe Flash Player
>   software is available with Mac OS X
>   v10.6.4 and later on hardware
>   supported by the Mac OS Video Decode
>   Acceleration Framework (such as the
>   NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, GeForce 320M,
>   and GeForce GT 330M). Whether hardware
>   decoding will engage for a specific
>   video is determined by the Mac OS
>   Video Decode Acceleration Framework.
>   View hardware used by different Mac
>   models

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The technical note on the Video Decode Acceleration Framework linked to from the Mac section in your source mentions Intel HD graphics a couple times, so that's promising. I really want to know about Linux support, though.